What does Kapila Githa say about pregnant women?
What does it say about children in the womb of their mother? Do they remember their past life? What are the feelings of the child in its mothers womb?

Hi, welcome to HSE! In addition to 'accepting' answers, it is also courteous to give the answerer an upvote if it was helpful.

In srimad bhagavatam it is said,

The child thus remains just like a bird in a cage, without freedom of movement. At that time, if the child is fortunate, he can remember all the troubles of his past one hundred births, and he grieves wretchedly. What is the possibility of peace of mind in that condition?
(3.31.9)


Thus endowed with the development of consciousness from the seventh month after his conception, the child is tossed downward by the airs that press the embryo during the weeks preceding delivery. Like the worms born of the same filthy abdominal cavity, he cannot remain in one place.(3.31.10)


The human soul says: I take shelter of the lotus feet of the Supreme Personality of Godhead, who appears in His various eternal forms and walks on the surface of the world. I take shelter of Him only, because He can give me relief from all fear and from Him I have received this condition of life, which is just befitting my impious activities.

So we can say he remembers his past births and has a miserable condition there.
To read complete you can visit vedabase
